# $\{p_n\}$ is a convergent sequence while $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|p_n − p_{n+1}|$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Give an example of a convergent sequence $\{p_n\}$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|p_n − p_{n+1}|$ diverges.

I had another question that was the 'opposite' of this i.e. $p_n$ diverges and the difference converges which I had little trouble completing using Cauchy, but I'm drawing a blank on this example.

Comment: A helpful tool is the alternating series test: if you have a series whose terms alternate in sign, then as long as the magnitude of the terms monotonically decreases to $0$, the series converges, no matter how slow the magnitude decreases (as long as it is to zero). Now, choose an alternating series where the magnitude decreases very slowly, and let $p_n$ be the $n$th partial sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example $p_n=(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}$ converges by the alternating series test. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |p_n-p_{n+1}|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)>2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$$which diverges

Answer (score 3):

For your first question, something like

$$\left\{0, \frac 12 , 0, \frac 13, 0, \frac 14, 0, \cdots\right\}$$

would do. For the opposite question, if 
$$\tag{1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty |p_n - p_{n+1}|$$
converges, then $\{p_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence (thus is convergent). To see this, let $\epsilon >0$. Then as $(1)$ converges, there is $N_\epsilon \in \mathbb N$ so that 
$$\sum_{n = N_\epsilon} ^\infty |p_n - p_{n+1}| <\epsilon.$$
Then for all $n, m\ge N_\epsilon$, $n<m$, we have 
$$\begin{split}|p_n - p_m| &= |p_n - p_{n+1} + p_{n+1} - p_{n+2} + \cdots -p_{m-1} + p_{m-1}  -p_m|\\
&\le |p_n - p_{n+1}| + |p_{n+1} - p_{n+2}|+ \cdots + |p_{m-1}- p_m|\\
& \le \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} |p_k- p_{k+1}| <\epsilon.
\end{split}$$
Thus $\{p_n\}$ is Cauchy.